# ORACLE SQL Query - test a list of keys for NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with columns K1, K2, V, where (K1,K2) is a composite primary key. I have a list of K1 values 'possiblyNew'. I would like to find all values in that list that have no matches in the table, e.g. (have no idea on proper syntax here)

```
SELECT PN.K1
FROM [some way of specifying the list inline] as PN 
WHERE PN.K1 NOT IN (SELECT T.K1 from myTable T)
```

This is using Oracle 12. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have a list of K1 values 'possiblyNew'"

So the question is, *where* do you have these values? You need to get them into a SQL construct so you can use them in a query.

Let's assume they are numbers, so you can instantiate an array of the collection `sys.odcinumberlist` with them. Doing this allows you to put them in the FROM clause through the `table()` function:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

        K1         K2 V
---------- ---------- ---------
         1          2 27-JUL-17
         2          1 06-JUL-17
         4          3 29-JUL-17

SQL> select column_value
  2  from table( sys.odcinumberlist ( 2, 3, 4, 5))
  3  where column_value not in
  4      ( select k1 from t1)
  5  /

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           3
           5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your values on a table, try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE (K1, K2) NOT IN ( SELECT K1, K2 FROM TABLE_B )
```

If not, you could try one of those:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE K1 NOT IN ( 'k1', 'k2', 'k3', ..., 'kn' )
```

or

```
WITH myList AS (
    SELECT 'k1' AS K
    UNION
    SELECT 'k2'
)
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE K1 NOT IN ( SELECT K FROM myList )
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE MY_VALUES ( ... )
INSERT INTO MY_VALUES ( 'k2' );
INSERT INTO MY_VALUES ( 'k1' );
...
INSERT INTO MY_VALUES ( 'kn' );
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE K1 NOT IN ( SELECT K1 FROM MY_VALUES )
```